# How can I use this function on all files in a folder in R and save the outputs to new files?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply, data-cleaning

I have written some code that I need to apply to 62 files. I imagine that I can use a for loop or lapply function in some way, but am struggling to come up with some thing that works. Here is the function I wrote to clean the data:

```
clean.data <- function(messyData){

#remove rows with NA
messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, Name != 'NA')

#remove rows containing "similar" in Name
messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, !grepl('Similar', Name))

#standardize column 8 name (P_value_T)
names(messyData)[8]<-"P_value_T" 

#remove p-vals > .05
messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, P_value_T < .05)
messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, P_value_T != 'NA')

#remove duplicates
messyData <- messyData[!duplicated(messyData$Name),]

#keep only names
cleanData <- messyData[, c("Name")]

return(cleanData)
}
```

When I run the following:

```
messydf <- read.csv("res2.csv", na.strings = c("", "NA"), header = TRUE)
table <- clean.data(messydf)
write.table(table, file="res2_cleaned.txt", sep="\t", quote=FALSE)
```

I get the proper output as a .txt!
[text file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvADy.png)

Now I need to do the same for res3.csv, res4.csv, etc. and save them to new files maybe res3_clean.csv, res4_clean.csv, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Include reading and writing file into the function as well :

```
clean.data <- function(filename){
  messydf <- read.csv(filename, na.strings = c("", "NA"), header = TRUE)
  #remove rows with NA
  messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, Name != 'NA')
  
  #remove rows containing "similar" in Name
  messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, !grepl('Similar', Name))
  
  #standardize column 8 name (P_value_T)
  names(messyData)[8]<-"P_value_T" 
  
  #remove p-vals > .05
  messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, P_value_T < .05)
  messyData <- dplyr::filter(messyData, P_value_T != 'NA')
  
  #remove duplicates
  messyData <- messyData[!duplicated(messyData$Name),]
  
  #keep only names
  cleanData <- messyData[, c("Name")]
  
  write.table(table, file= paste0('cleaned_', filename), sep="\t", quote=FALSE)
}
```

Now assuming all the files that you want to read and change are in your working directory you can use `list.files` to get filenames and apply the function using `lapply`.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '^res')
lapply(files, clean.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is fairly elegant but not initially intuitive. Also, without reproducible code/data, this was a little tricky but I believe this should work.

Assuming that your files are all within the same folder in your working directory (WD), you can make a list of all of the files within the folder with the `list.files(pattern='*.csv')` function (note: it's very important you have your WD correctly specified). Then, create an empty list to store the "cleaned" data from the loop. From the list of "unclean" data, the loop saves each .csv file *i* as 'dat', applies your `data.clean()` function, writes that .txt file to your WD (with a name based on the first four characters of the .csv file name; e.g. res5.csv is now res5_cleaned.txt), and stores those cleaned .txt files into your WD. The code below should be all you need.

```
setwd("~your working directory") # Or setwd within "Session" --> "Set Working Directory"

file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')  # Grabs data from WD and stores as list

clean.list <- vector("list", length(file.list)) # Empty list to store cleaned data

for(i in 1:length(file.list)){
  
  dat = read.csv(file.list[i], row.names = NULL) 
  
  clean.list[[i]] = clean.data(dat) # <-- Your function 
  
  file.name = paste(substr(file.list[i], start = 1, stop = 4), '_clean.txt', sep = "")
  
  write.table(clean.list[[i]], file = file.name)
}
```

You may need to adjust the file naming line along with however you want the data to be exported (.txt, .csv, etc). Hopefully this works for you! Stay well!